# Why redux actions needs to be serializable?

Tags: reactjs, redux, recoiljs, zustand

https://redux.js.org/faq/actions#why-should-type-be-a-string-or-at-least-serializable-why-should-my-action-types-be-constants

> While it is certainly possible to manually create action objects everywhere, and write each type value by hand, defining reusable constants makes maintaining code easier.

I don't feel ***easy*** at all. 95% of my actions are used once or twice. Anyone feel writing actions are beneficial?

#### Background

I got mad writing redux actions. Even for libs like zustand need action. So I decided to write an anonymous function to automatically change state for me. Hence the warning.

```
reducer: (state, action) => {
    let newState = { ...state };
    if (action.type === "func") {
      newState = produce(state, action.func); // import produce from 'immer'  
    }

    return newState;
  },
```

Comment: learn redux-toolkit.  you wont need to write actions and types. it will automatically generate just by writing a slicer

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible and can be done but serialization of actons enable several of Redux's defining features, such as time travel debugging, and recording and replaying actions. As an example: time travel debugging means redux knows when new thread for a specific time is resolved and can be checked back by the store to re-render the Components. Writing it in un-serialable way, redux does not keep this track.

Comment: Redux devtools time travel does not use serialization of actions. I am still able to time travel because the tool keep track of the state difference.

Or my question should be, why named actions while state diff is enough for time travel?

Comment: Tme travel done by redux once actions are seriable are more efficient and it adds much more efficiency to it in other ways too. However, this increases Space complexity of code which is minimizes in Redux Tool kit and ignoreable because when there is debate of Space Compolexity and Computational Power, Computational Power wins. Writing actions seriable makes the computations for time travel lesser.

Comment: @jchnxu : I know we chatted on Github, but trust me: **the Redux Devtools most definitely _do_ require serialization of actions in order to work right!**  That's how the DevTools can see the actions to begin with. They have to be sent from the app code in the page process, over to the extension UI in the outer browser process, and that requires serialization across processes.

Comment: @markerikson Thank you mark for your patience all over the web! The idea of event driven design started to grow on me. It's the core of flux to de-couple updating state with pub-sub pattern. If there's no need for pub-sub I can definitely abandon the flux pattern.